# Why didn't Hamas take West Bank from Fatah in 2007?

Tags: palestine, middle-east, gaza, hamas, jerusalem

Hamas and Fatah fought for the Gaza Strip in [2007](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Gaza_(2007)). As a result Hamas took over the strip.

But Hamas has showed many times they care for East Jerusalem (al-Quds in Arabic) very much.

They have the chant "القدس لنا" which means al-Quds is for us. Also, their recent brutal attack against Israel has the codename "طوفان الاقصی" which means "[al-Aqsa storm](https://www.moroccoworldnews.com/2023/10/358263/report-hamass-operation-storm-al-aqsa-shattered-israels-security-myth)" (al-Aqsa is the name of an important mosque in East Jerusalem).

Why didn't they take West Bank from Fatah if they care for East Jerusalem and its belongings so much? Why did they intend to take Gaza from Fatah from the start?

Comment: My vague recollection from articles back then: WB is less compact so more Israeli presence interfering; they were perhaps less liked even among Palestinians in the WB, back then.

Comment: Probably more the former than the latter, given the election results https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Palestinian_election_map,_2006.svg

Comment: And now they aren't liked even in the Gaza Strip itself.

Comment: Wikipedia also [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatah%E2%80%93Hamas_conflict#West_Bank_clashes) that in terms of armed guys "Although Hamas's numbers were greater in the Gaza Strip, Fatah forces were greater in the West Bank." But it doesn't cite a source for that.

Comment: The whole reason for the civil war between Fatah and Hamas is because the US supports Fatah, and doesn't like Hamas. Thus, the Americans armed Fatah to fight the Hamas. While Hamas emerged stronger from it, it weakened the Palestinian cause and Fatah continues to exist. Fighting Fatah without a sure fire way of defeating it would make them unpopular among the Palestinians and the other Arab states.

Answer (score -2):

The West Bank is controlled by Fatah.

Hamas can't just "take" the West Bank (as you seem to suggest) without first defeating Fatah in the West Bank (as it successfully did in Gaza).

(This question is similar to asking why North Korea didn't just take South Korea or vice versa during the Korean War.)

Comment: First of all, this doesn't answer the question. It just says Hamas can't take the West Bank without a war. But doesn't say why Hamas didn't intend to take the territory at all. They could fight in the West Bank instead of Gaza.

Comment: Also, I know the West Bank is controlled by Fatah and I didn't suggest Hamas can take it from them without a war. Clearly I said in the question body that Fatah-controlled Gaza was taken with a war. How can I say the West Bank can be taken without a war? I just didn't use the word war. But you should've realized from my speaking about Gaza that I suggested the same thing about the West Bank.